# iterate an array of strings and perform a regexp

Tags: ruby, regex, arrays, string, datetime

Given an array of DateTime Strings, I want to just fetch the times e.g. `10:30:00`.
So far I come up with this, but it wont give me the right result:

```
["2011-07-30 10:00:00","2011-07-30 12:00:00"].each{|item| item.match(/\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}/)}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If all the strings really are like that then just do some substring mangling:

```
a     = ["2011-07-30 10:00:00","2011-07-30 12:00:00"]
times = a.map { |e| e[11,8] }
```

This will also work if your timestamps include things like `2011-07-30 10:00:00.1123`, `2011-07-30T10:00:00`, or `2011-07-30 10:00:00 +0700`.

If you wanted to be friendlier to the future, then you could do this:

```
off   = '9999-99-99 '.length
len   = '99:99:99'.length
times = a.map { |e| e[off, len] }
```

so no one would have to guess what the `11` and `8` were all about.

Answer (score 4):

You could achieve the same using the excellent [DateTime](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/date/rdoc/classes/DateTime.html) library from Ruby.

```
require 'date'

["2011-07-30 10:00:00","2011-07-30 12:00:00"].map{|item|
  DateTime.parse(item).strftime("%H:%M:%S")
}
 => ["10:00:00", "12:00:00"]
```

Though, mu's answer is great.

Comment: +1 for the use of ruby DateTime lib, IMO this answer is better than reinventing the wheel.